# How to fix "The following resource(s) failed to update: [Cloudfront]."

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

#### Update

There are other errors that show up after this error, but it seems clear to me (based on the timestamps, descriptions and affected resources) that they're just failures that happen because they depend on this first failing step. They are:

```
UPDATE_FAILED: Resource update cancelled
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS: [OtherResource1, OtherResource2,...]
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS (no associated message)
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE (no associated message)
```

---

I'm getting this error

> The following resource(s) failed to update: [Cloudfront].

when trying to redeploy my cloudformation stack. This is the template file:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: 'Cloudfront stack'
Parameters:
  ViewerRequestFunctionVersionArn:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
  OringResponseFunctionVersionArn:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
  LambdaVideoPathEdgeVersionArn:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
  DNSDomainName:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
    MaxLength: 150
    MinLength: 5
  S3VideoDNSDomainName:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
    MaxLength: 150
    MinLength: 5
  IdParam:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
    MaxLength: 150
    MinLength: 5
  IdVideoOriginParam:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
    MaxLength: 150
    MinLength: 5
  OrigingAccessIdentityID:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
    MaxLength: 450
    MinLength: 5
  OrigingAccessIdentityVideoID:
    Type: String
    Description: S3bucketStack Name that your want to import the DNSDomainName from.
    MaxLength: 450
    MinLength: 5
  SSLCertificate:
    Type: String
    Description: SSLCertificate ARN .
    MaxLength: 150
    MinLength: 5
  Comment:
    Type: String
    Description: SSLCertificate ARN .
    MaxLength: 450
    MinLength: 5
  CommentOrigin:
    Type: String
    Description: SSLCertificate ARN .
    MaxLength: 450
    MinLength: 5
  AllowedMethodsParam:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: Buket Name for website config( eg exemple.com).
  CachedMethodsParam:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: Buket Name for website config( eg exemple.com).
  AliasesParam:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: Buket Name for website config( eg exemple.com).
  defaultTTLParam:
    Type: Number
    Description: SSLCertificate ARN .
Resources:
  CloudFrontDistribution:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig: 
        Aliases: !Ref AliasesParam
        Comment: !Ref Comment
        CacheBehaviors:
          - AllowedMethods: !Ref AllowedMethodsParam
            CachedMethods: !Ref CachedMethodsParam
            Compress: false
            DefaultTTL: !Ref defaultTTLParam 
            PathPattern: 'public/*'
            ForwardedValues:
              Headers: 
                - Access-Control-Request-Headers
                - Access-Control-Request-Method
                - Origin
              QueryString: true
            MaxTTL: 31536000
            MinTTL: 0
            SmoothStreaming: false
            TargetOriginId: !Ref IdParam
            ViewerProtocolPolicy : "redirect-to-https"
          - AllowedMethods: !Ref AllowedMethodsParam
            CachedMethods: !Ref CachedMethodsParam
            Compress: false
            DefaultTTL: !Ref defaultTTLParam 
            PathPattern: 'images/*'
            ForwardedValues:
              Headers: 
                - Access-Control-Request-Headers
                - Access-Control-Request-Method
                - Origin
              QueryString: true
              QueryStringCacheKeys:
                - w
                - h
                - t 
                - q
                - v
            LambdaFunctionAssociations:
              - EventType: 'viewer-request'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref ViewerRequestFunctionVersionArn
              - EventType: 'origin-response'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref OringResponseFunctionVersionArn
            MaxTTL: 31536000
            MinTTL: 0
            SmoothStreaming: false
            TargetOriginId: !Ref IdParam
            ViewerProtocolPolicy : "redirect-to-https"
          - AllowedMethods: !Ref AllowedMethodsParam
            CachedMethods: !Ref CachedMethodsParam
            Compress: false
            PathPattern: 'videos/thumbnails/*'
            DefaultTTL: !Ref defaultTTLParam 
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: true
              QueryStringCacheKeys:
                - w
                - h
                - t 
                - q
                - v
            LambdaFunctionAssociations:
              - EventType: 'viewer-request'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref ViewerRequestFunctionVersionArn
              - EventType: 'origin-request'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref LambdaVideoPathEdgeVersionArn
              - EventType: 'origin-response'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref OringResponseFunctionVersionArn
            MaxTTL: 31536000
            MinTTL: 0
            SmoothStreaming: false
            TargetOriginId: !Ref IdParam
            ViewerProtocolPolicy : "redirect-to-https"
          - AllowedMethods: !Ref AllowedMethodsParam
            CachedMethods: !Ref CachedMethodsParam
            Compress: false
            PathPattern: 'videos/*'
            DefaultTTL: !Ref defaultTTLParam 
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: true
              QueryStringCacheKeys:
                - codex
            LambdaFunctionAssociations:
              - EventType: 'viewer-request'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref ViewerRequestFunctionVersionArn
              - EventType: 'origin-request'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref LambdaVideoPathEdgeVersionArn
              - EventType: 'origin-response'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref OringResponseFunctionVersionArn
            MaxTTL: 31536000
            MinTTL: 0
            SmoothStreaming: false
            TargetOriginId: !Ref IdVideoOriginParam
            ViewerProtocolPolicy : "redirect-to-https"
          - AllowedMethods: !Ref AllowedMethodsParam
            CachedMethods: !Ref CachedMethodsParam
            Compress: false
            PathPattern: 'gifs/*'
            DefaultTTL: !Ref defaultTTLParam
            LambdaFunctionAssociations:
              - EventType: 'viewer-request'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref ViewerRequestFunctionVersionArn
              - EventType: 'origin-request'
                LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref LambdaVideoPathEdgeVersionArn
            MaxTTL: 31536000
            MinTTL: 0
            SmoothStreaming: false
            TargetOriginId: !Ref IdParam
            ViewerProtocolPolicy : "redirect-to-https"
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: false
          AllowedMethods: !Ref AllowedMethodsParam
          CachedMethods: !Ref CachedMethodsParam
          Compress: false
          DefaultTTL: !Ref defaultTTLParam 
          MaxTTL: 31536000
          MinTTL: 0
          SmoothStreaming: false
          TargetOriginId: !Ref IdParam
          ViewerProtocolPolicy : "redirect-to-https"
          LambdaFunctionAssociations:
            - EventType: 'viewer-request'
              LambdaFunctionARN: !Ref ViewerRequestFunctionVersionArn
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        IPV6Enabled: true
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !Ref DNSDomainName
            Id: !Ref IdParam
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${OrigingAccessIdentityID}"
          - DomainName: !Ref S3VideoDNSDomainName
            Id: !Ref IdVideoOriginParam
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${OrigingAccessIdentityVideoID}"
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref SSLCertificate
          MinimumProtocolVersion: "TLSv1.1_2016"
          SslSupportMethod: "sni-only"
      Tags: 
        - Key: Application
          Value: Testing
        - Key: Distribution
          Value: Coudfront HTTPS
Outputs:
  DomainName:
    Value: !GetAtt CloudFrontDistribution.DomainName
    Description: Cloudfront DomainName
```

I've reviewed the [cloudfront troubleshooting guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html) and the closest thing that I thought may be a cause was differences between the deployed resources and what the template specifies. So I reverted all the changes I'd made in the dashboard and tried redeploying, but the error persisted. What else can I try? Or is there more info I can provide to shed more light on the problem?

Comment: Were there not any other error messages?

Comment: @tianz I've updated the question to show the other error messages that arise, but as I mentioned in the update I think those failures happen because of the first cloudfront failure. Let me know if you need more info.